# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in python OOP

Tags: python, oop

Im creating a simple guessing game that involves 2 players in Python OOP. Im trying to make the code print lower if the guess is higher than the number but it puts an error under the number variable

**code**

```py
import random

class Players:

    def __init__(self, user1, user2):
        self.user1 = user1
        self.user2 = user2

        self.user1_score = 0
        self.user2_score = 0

    def users(self):
        print(f"""Users: 
        User 1: {self.user1}
        User 2: {self.user2}""")

class Guess(Players):

    def guess(self):

        number = random.randint(0, 100)

        print(f"{self.user1}'s turn")
        user1_guesses = 0
        while user1_guesses < 3:
            guess = input("Enter guess: ")

            if guess > number:
                print("lower")
                user1_guesses += 1

            if guess == number:
                print(f"{self.user1} won!")
                self.user1_score += 1
                print(f"{self.user1}'s score: {self.user1_score} points")


game = Guess("luke", "yoda")
game.users()
game.guess()
```

**error**

```py
            if guess > number:
                print("lower")
                user1_guesses += 1
```

the error is under number, it says "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

When you take an input on python, it is taken as a string. So yes, you're actually comparing `if str > int`. You may want to parse the input to int before continuing and you can also do it in one line.

Change this:

```
guess = input("Enter guess: ")
```

To this:

```
guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
```

*Take in consideration doing just this won't handle errors and will crash if user inputs something that is not a number.*