# I am making a guessing game but I have problems with it. What should I do?

Tags: python, typeerror

So this is my code:

```
import random
def guess(x):
      random_number = random.randint(1, x)
      guess = 0
      while guess != random_number:
            guess = input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:')
            if guess < random_number:
                       print('Sorry, Guess again. Too low.')
            elif guess > random_number:
                       print('Sorry. Guess again. Too high')
print(f'Yay, Congrats. You have guessed the number {random_number} correctly!')
guess(10)
```

but I am getting these errors:
line 15, in <module>
guess(10)

and
line 8, in guess
if guess < random_number:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `input` returns a string. `random.randint` returns an int. You can't compare them. Cast `guess` to an int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950021/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Comment: `guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))`.  Note that this will raise an exception (and end the function early if it's uncaught) if the user enters something that can't be interpreted as an int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in python OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274941/typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int-in-python-oop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import random
def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))
        if guess < random_number:
            print('Sorry, Guess again. Too low.')
        elif guess > random_number:
            print('Sorry. Guess again. Too high')
    print(f'Yay, Congrats. You have guessed the number {random_number} correctly!')
guess(10)
```

Output:

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10: 4
Sorry, Guess again. Too low.
Guess a number between 1 and 10: 6
Sorry. Guess again. Too high
Guess a number between 1 and 10: 5
Yay, Congrats. You have guessed the number 5 correctly!
```

Your code had two problems: the indentation was not correct, and everything read from `input()` is a string. To fix that I just converted the number read from `input()` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

While catasaurus' answer is correct in the syntax errors, the function to print both the guess is too high and the guess is too low is redundant.

Try something like this...

```
    import random
    def guess(x):
        random_number = random.randint(1, x)
        guess = 0
        while guess != random_number:
            guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}:'))
            if guess < random_number:
                print('Sorry, Guess again. Too low.')
            if guess > random_number:
                print('Sorry. Guess again. Too high'
        print(f'Yay, Congrats. You have guessed the number {random_number} correctly!')
    guess(10)
```

It returns...

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10:7
Sorry. Guess again. Too high
Guess a number between 1 and 10:5
Sorry, Guess again. Too low.
Guess a number between 1 and 10:6
Yay, Congrats. You have guessed the number 6 correctly!
```